# Configure subdomain with nginx

Tags: nginx, openedx

I have Linux ubuntu where I installed [Open edX](https://open.edx.org/) and [Drupal](http://drupal.org). Open Edx using nginx and so I prefer to use nginx with Drupal too to avoid installing more packages for apache and load the machin.

I would like to have the main domain (e.g. example.com) pointing to the Drupal website and subdomain (e.g. learn.example.com) to point the Open edX website.

How to configure nginx to do that?

Comment: Just set up 2 separate `server {....}` instances. Set their respective `server_name` values to the required `example.com` & `learn.example.com` and point the `root` values of each of those in the right direction. [**This**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) should give you a general understanding of what you could do :)

Comment: Thanks @Darren , I followed the link and it works

Comment: Glad you resolved it mate!